# DisplayTag pagination is not retained after sorting

Tags: jsp, sorting, spring-mvc, pagination, displaytag

Everything I require is working fine until I face the following problem .
I am using displayTag to use sorting and pagination . But the problem is when i am on 4th page for example and click on any column for sorting then control is going back to 1st page by default. Its should be ob 4th page only (Ideally speaking).Following is the code that i written .

display.jsp

```
    <div class="tableDisp">
                <display:table id="person" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" keepStatus="true"  class="tableDisplay"  excludedParams="*" requestURI="/getAllMember.htm" name="${command}" sort="list" pagesize="5" >

                  <display:column  title="Name" sortable="true" sortProperty="personName" >${person.personName}</display:column>
                  <display:column  title="DOB" sortable="true" sortProperty="dob" >${person.dob}</display:column>
                  <display:column  title="phone Number" sortable="true" sortProperty="phoneNo" >${person.phoneNo}</display:column>
                  <display:column  title="profile creation Date" sortable="true" sortProperty="profilecreationDate" >${person.profilecreationDate}</display:column>
                  <display:column  title="Gender" sortable="true" sortProperty="gender" >${person.gender}</display:column>

                 </display:table>
                </div>
```

Contrller.java

```
    List<Person> persons = searchService.getAllPerson();
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("memberPage");
            mav.addObject("command",persons);
            return mav;
```

I am using displayTag-1.2.jar. Please Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to sort the whole list and remain on the current page rather than just sort the current page (which can be done by specifying sort="page").

If so looks like you are out of luck. See the following demo and comments below which note that:

> When sorting is enabled on the full list, the page number is
>   automatically reset if you change the sorted column or the sort order.

http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-pse.jsp?d-49653-s=0&d-49653-o=2&d-49653-p=1

Comment: So what are saying is this requirement is not possible..?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the below into `displaytag.properties`

   ```
   pagination.sort.skippagenumber=false
   ```
2. You nead to make sure <display:table name="***must be a paginatedList***" .../>
3. In you action class, use the following to get sort/page parematers

   ```
    String sPageNumber=request.getParameter(new ParamEncoder("project").encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_PAGE));<br>
    String sortCriterion=request.getParameter(org.displaytag.properties.TableProperties.getInstance(request).getPaginationSortParam());<br>
    String sortDirection=request.getParameter(org.displaytag.properties.TableProperties.getInstance(request).getPaginationSortDirectionParam());<br>
   ```
4. Change source code of HtmlTableWriter, line 539:

   ```
    if (properties.getPaginationSkipPageNumberInSort())
        {
            href.removeParameter(properties.getPaginationPageNumberParam());
        }else {
             href.addParameter(properties.getPaginationPageNumberParam(), paginatedList.getPageNumber());
        }
   ```